# How can I move a column from one table to a new table?

Tags: sql, sqlite, refactoring

I'd like to refactor my database by splitting a single table into two.  I'd like to moving a few existing columns to a new table.  For instance, suppose I want to move the `address` field in the below `Employee` table to a new `Address` table.

How can I accomplish this **using sqlite** (or SQL if equivalent)?

**Before:**

```
Employee Table
   employee_id (Primary)
   name
   address
   city
```

**After:**

```
Employee Table
   employee_id (Primary)
   name
   address_id

Address Table
   address_id (Primary)
   address
   city
```

Comment: Can you give some detail about address id..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
  CREATE TABLE Employee(
  emp_id int,
  name nvarchar(50),
  address nvarchar(50),
  city nvarchar(50),
  PRIMARY KEY (emp_Id));

ALTER TABLE Employee
ADD address_id int NOT NULL IDENTITY;

INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE(emp_id,name,address,city) VALUES (111,'JOHN','XXX STREET','XYZ');

CREATE TABLE Address(
   address_id int NOT NULL,
   address nvarchar(100),
   city nvarchar(100),
   PRIMARY KEY (address_id)
  );

INSERT INTO Address (address_id, address, city)
SELECT address_id, address, city
FROM Employee;

ALTER TABLE Employee
DROP COLUMN address;

ALTER TABLE Employee
DROP COLUMN city;
```

Check [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/23055)

Comment: `address_id` is a new primary key for each address row.

Comment: The value should be auto increment or input by user..?

Comment: Auto generated is just fine, I thought this was implicit from the context--I'm just splitting a table in two.

Answer (score 1):

```
create table employee_new(employee_id,name,address_id);
insert into employee_new select employee_id,name,employee_id from employee;
create table address(address_id,address,city);
insert into address select employee_id,address,city from employee; 
alter table employee rename to employee_old;
alter table employee_new rename to employee;
```

Comment: You can shamelessly use the value of employee_id as address_id in migration, in future you cannot of course rely that they are same. And the syntax here is sqlite compliant (skipped the data types).

Comment: Thanks Toni, I actually can't rely on that because in the real use for this code, I will actually be creating more than one address per employee.  Would you like me to post a new followup question or modify the existing one to mention this?

Comment: Modifying this is ok. Where do you get the new addresses? Are there multiple rows per employee_id now in Employee table?

Comment: No need to drop columns, you just drop the employee_old once you've validated that the migration has been successful: `drop table employee_old;`

Answer (score 0):

1: Create the AddressID column in your first table and assign a number.
2: Create the new table empty.
3: Transfer the data (something like this)
        INSERT INTO ADDRESS (ADDRESS_ID, ADDRESS, CITY)
        SELECT ADDRESS_ID, ADDRESS, CITY FROM EMPLOYEE
4: Remove the old columns from the first table and create the foreign keys